Vectorization or something relatively near to C speed, where each result depends on the prior result. Currently using Pandas apply() w/o explicit loop
Having as input Pandas dataframes with Boolean values columns (True/False or 1/0) like the following example, but also knowing that if that speeds up the calculations then instead of dataframes columns, the input can be modified to come in form of arrays:
     enabler1  disabler1  enabler2  disabler2
0       False      False     False      False
1        True      False     False      False
2        True      False     False      False
3       False      False      True      False
4       False       True     False      False
5       False      False     False      False
6       False      False      True      False
7       False      False     False      False
8       False      False     False       True
9       False      False     False      False
10      False      False     False      False
11       True      False     False      False
12      False       True     False      False
13      False      False      True      False
14      False      False     False      False
15      False      False      True      False
16      False      False     False      False
17      False      False     False       True
18      False      False     False      False
19      False      False     False      False

Then, a result column is needed in the next way, being calculated based on columns enabler1, disabler1, enabler2, disabler2 and at the same time also based on result previous value:
     enabler1  disabler1  enabler2  disabler2  result
0       False      False     False      False       0
1        True      False     False      False       1
2        True      False     False      False       1
3       False      False      True      False       1
4       False       True     False      False       0
5       False      False     False      False       0
6       False      False      True      False      -1
7       False      False     False      False      -1
8       False      False     False       True       0
9       False      False     False      False       0
10      False      False     False      False       0
11       True      False     False      False       1
12      False       True     False      False       0
13      False      False      True      False      -1
14      False      False     False      False      -1
15      False      False      True      False      -1
16      False      False     False      False      -1
17      False      False     False       True       0
18      False      False     False      False       0
19      False      False     False      False       0

As you may notice, the result column is equivalent to a variable, that in a classic for loop, keeps a kind of ON value (see below) until a corresponding disabler "resets" its value to OFF (default value).
I'm looking for other points of view, trying to achieve the fastest and more efficient possible way to handle this kind of situations with calculations based on previous values of the same column/list/array.
I understand there could be simplified solutions based on Numba to for example make a for loop run faster, but specifically about this question I'm trying to avoid explicit Python loops in case it is the most suitable solution.
Please note this is to work either in .ipynb files (Jupyter Notebook or VSC), or also in .py files.

Here is the most recent progress, still in development, with no-explicit Python loop:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame({
    'enabler1': [False, True, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
    'disabler1': [False, False, False, False, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
    'enabler2': [False, False, False, True, False, False, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, True, False, True, False, False, False, False],
    'disabler2': [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, True, False, False]
})

df['result'] = None
#Here also tried with `df['result'] = np.nan` and `df['result'] = 0` but they raise the next warning:
#FutureWarning: Setting an item of incompatible dtype is deprecated and will raise an error in a future version of pandas"...
#..."Value has dtype incompatible with int64, please explicitly cast to a compatible dtype first."

... The next code goes right after the previous one, just divided to be shown here in a view without vertical scroll.
def myFuntion(enabler_1, disabler_1, enabler_2, disabler_2):
    global tempResult #The idea with this variable is to have its most recent previous value.

    #These 6 conditions can be reduced to 3, but here just trying to better show the different possible cases:

    conditions = [
        (tempResult == 0) & (enabler_1 == True) & (disabler_1 == False) & (enabler_2 == False),
        (tempResult == 0) & (enabler_2 == True) & (disabler_2 == False) & (enabler_1 == False),
        (tempResult == 1) & (disabler_1 == True),
        (tempResult == -1) & (disabler_2 == True),
        (tempResult == 1) & (disabler_1 == False),
        (tempResultl == -1) & (disabler_2 == False),
    ]

    choices = [
        1,
        -1,
        0,
        0,
        1,
        -1,
    ]

    tempResult = np.select(conditions, choices, default=0) #tempResult = np.select(conditions, choices)
    
    return tempResult


df.loc[0, 'result'] = 0 #default initial value in the first row.

df.loc[1:, 'result'] = df.loc[1:].apply(lambda row: myFuntion(*row[['enabler1', 'disabler1', 'enabler2', 'disabler2']]), axis=1)

print(df)


Update 1: 
As a reference for a clearer visualization, here is a code version with an explicit Python loop that produces the same result. Here you can see the exact conditions needed to obtain a type of ON value (non-zero value, 1 or -1) and also the conditions to obtain an OFF value (0):
df['result'] = 0


def myFuntionLoop(enabler1, disabler1, enabler2, disabler2): 
    tempResult = 0  #The intial default value in `result` is `0`.
    resultList = [0] * len(enabler1)  #A list with the needed length and with `0` as initial values.

    for i in range(1, len(enabler1)):  #Starting from the row 1, i.e. skipping the row 0.
        if tempResult == 0 and enabler1[i] and disabler1[i] == False and enabler2[i] == False:
            tempResult = 1
        elif tempResult == 0 and enabler2[i] and disabler2[i] == False and enabler1[i] == False:
            tempResult = -1
        elif tempResult == 1 and disabler1[i] == True:
            tempResult = 0
        elif tempResult == -1 and disabler2[i] == True:
            tempResult = 0
        
        resultList[i] = tempResult

    return resultList


df['result'] = myFuntionLoop(df['enabler1'], df['disabler1'], df['enabler2'], df['disabler2'])


print(df)


Considerations for the specific situation described in this thread, that can help to obtain a more efficient solution, especially in solutions based on vectors or arrays calculations:


In this scheme, the input is given in a Pandas dataframe form, but this can be modified and maybe a better approach would be to start from arrays instead of dataframe columns, and later in a final step after the result array is calculated then building the dataframe with the 5 columns.

tempResult is just an integer variable that stores a kind of status, with OFF as default value (0), and two types of ON values (1 or -1) when the corresponding condition is met then.

To obtain a non-zero result value (1 or -1) in any row, both enablers can't be True at the same time. This is under any condition even if the recent prior tempResult value is 0.

The most basic part in the conditions to obtain a non-zero result value is that the recent prior tempResult value needs to be 0, so if the tempResult value is already a type of ON value, then there is not even the need to evaluate again a condition that produces any type of ON value, e.g. if the recent prior tempResult value is 1 then there are no conditions to evaluate a possible new 1 or -1 value, and exactly the same applies if the recent prior tempResult value is -1.

There aren't situations where in the same row the dataframes have 
tempResult == 1 & disabler2 == True nor tempResult == -1 & disabler1 == True. Thanks to @bogdan-shevchenko for highlighting this important part.

Rows where the 4 input columns are False, i.e. enabler1 = disabler1 = enabler2 = disabler2 = False, keep the recent prior result value, so these rows don't produce any changes in the previous value. The frequency of occurrence of this condition can vary in the input dataframes, however it is an extra point to take into consideration. Thanks to @bogdan-shevchenko for highlighting this important part.



Can you [edit] your question to precisely describe the logic for the results column?

Kind of oftopic: using pd.NA is compatible with Int64 dtype. More

Could you please provide full table of function logic? I mean, all 32 rows.
I.e. what if
(gPrevVal == -1) & (enabler_1 == True) & (disabler_1 == False) & (enabler_2 == False) & (disabler_2 == False)

Sure @bogdan-shevchenko, now the question contains the "Update 1" section, that includes a more classic logic with a for loop with if-statements that show the exact conditions to produce the result column either with this dataframe example or with other dataframes with the Boolean values in any other order. Also updated the variable name gPrevVal to tempResult because maybe is clearer to read.

@Anerdw, please check the new section "Update 1" in the question where is the logic to obtain the result column.

@codev, am I understanding right, that in my example answer will be -1?
And, same way, this input:
(gPrevVal == 0) & (enabler_1 == True) & (disabler_1 == False) & (enabler_2 == True) & (disabler_2 == False) - will gave us 0?

@bogdan-shevchenko, in the specific situation of this thread, yes, the condition you mention (tempResult == 0) & (enabler1 == True) & (disabler1 == False) & (enabler2 == True) & (disabler2 == False) will give 0, because to obtain a non-zero result, both enablers can't be True at the same time.

@bogdan-shevchenko, in the 1st example you put: (tempResult == -1) & (enabler1 == True) & (disabler1 == False) & (enabler2 == False) & (disabler2 == False) the result will be 0, because the most basic condition to get a non-zero result is that the recent prior tempResult value needs to be 0. The reason to not to write about every single scenario is to try to keep the question "brief", not having an even larger question, but of course I understand in some type of solutions it could be a key part. Thank you for your time, following the updates and helping others to have a better context

apply() is not always faster and sometimes for loop works better. Please check this: Link
Using numba() suits in this scenario, please refer to the below code,
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from numba import njit


df = pd.DataFrame({
    'enabler1': [False, True, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
    'disabler1': [False, False, False, False, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
    'enabler2': [False, False, False, True, False, False, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, True, False, True, False, False, False, False],
    'disabler2': [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, True, False, False]
})

df['result'] = 0


@njit
def calculate_result(enabler1, disabler1, enabler2, disabler2):
    result = np.zeros(enabler1.shape[0], dtype=np.int32)
    for i in range(1, len(enabler1)):
        prev_result = result[i-1]
        if prev_result == 0 and enabler1[i]:
            result[i] = 1
        elif prev_result == 0 and enabler2[i]:
            result[i] = -1
        elif prev_result == 1 and disabler1[i]:
            result[i] = 0
        elif prev_result == -1 and disabler2[i]:
            result[i] = 0
        else:
            result[i] = prev_result
    return result


df['result'] = calculate_result(df['enabler1'].values, df['disabler1'].values, df['enabler2'].values, df['disabler2'].values)

print(df)


Thank you @lisan-al-gaib for the answer. Yes, I know about using numba, but for this specific situation the question is mainly looking for an answer that hopefully work in a vectorized way, maybe directly in the NumPy layer, or in general without explicit loops (knowing that no explicit loops doesn't necessarily mean that is vectorized). So, I will leave the question open for other answers.

In your input, you want the previous row result to calculate the current one. so using a loop logic is inevitable. apply is not suitable for the requirement

I thank you for the answer and the explanation about apply(). I understand that in many answers loops would be part of possible solutions, but please note that when I mention to have an answer with no-explicit Python loop, is also understanding that there could be other kind of solutions maybe based on NumPy or other libraries that can include a loop "behind the scenes" in a lower layer (ideally in a C-layer). In many scenarios, your answer is a valid solution, and it is just that in this case I'm trying to see if the members here know about other creative solutions for this.

The only optimization I can see is next:
there are rows where next value is the same as previous (regardless of what exactly is previous data). I.e., if e1, d1, e2, d2 = False, False, False, False, next value=prev value, always. And, in fact, these rows could be excluded from calculations. You can leave them filled with NA and apply fillna at the end.
Like this:
def calculate_result(df):
    def inner(row, tempResult):
        if tempResult == 0 and row.enabler1:
            return 1
        ... # All logic with enablers/disablers
    global tempResult
    tempResult = 0
    noEffect = (
        (~df.enabler1 & ~df.disabler1 & ~df.enabler2 & ~df.disabler2)|
        (...)  # other possible combinations which don't change anything
    )
    for num, row in df[
        (noEffect == False) & 
        (df.index != df.index[0])
    ].iterrows():
        df.loc[num, 'result'] = tempResult = inner(row, tempResult)
    df['result'] = df.result.astype(pd.Int64Dtype()).ffill()
    return df
df = calculate_result(df)


In this case you just jump from one meaningful row to another, and don't spend time on those, which just copy the previous state
If you have a lot of such "empty" rows, it could be profitable
UPD
I think of an interesting and completely different approach, but it works only if there are no rows where previous_result = 1 and disable2 = True or vice versa previous_result = -1 and disable1 = True
If this is correct, we have only three status transformations: (0->1);(1->1);(-1->-1), (0->-1);(-1->-1);(1 -> 1), and anything->0.
Let us represent the status as a 3-dimensional vector
[a, b, 1], and the status itself could be retrieved from the vector with the next rules:

if a > b, the status is 1
if a < b, the status is -1
if a = b = 0, the status is 0

Status transformations in this case will be the next matrix operators:
0->1=  #multiplicator 3 could be in fact any number >=2
    [[3, 0, 0],
     [0, 3, 0],
     [1, 0, 1]]

0->-1=
    [[3, 0, 0],
     [0, 3, 0],
     [0, 1, 1]]

anything->0=
    [[0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 1]]

so, basically it means
1) a = a * 3 + 1; b = b * 3
2) a = a * 3; b = b * 3 + 1
3) a = 0; b = 0

As you can see, if a = 1 & b = 0 or b = 1 & a = 0, inequality will persist after any number of 1) and 2) transformations, and only if a = b = 0, 1.) and 2.) transformations will change the status.
Let's piece this together in the code:
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'enabler1': [False, True, True, False, False, False, False, 
                 False, False, False, False, True, False, False, 
                 False, False, False, False, False, False],
    'disabler1': [False, False, False, False, True, False, False, 
                  False, False, False, False, False, True, False, 
                  False, False, False, False, False, False],
    'enabler2': [False, False, False, True, False, False, True, 
                 False, False, False, False, False, False, True, 
                 False, True, False, False, False, False],
    'disabler2': [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, 
                  False, True, False, False, False, False, False, 
                  False, False, False, True, False, False]
})

e1 = np.array([[3, 0, 0],[0, 3, 0],[1, 0, 1]])
e2 = np.array([[3, 0, 0],[0, 3, 0],[0, 1, 1]])
d = np.array([[0, 0, 0],[0, 0, 0],[0, 0, 1]])
null = np.eye(3)
operators = np.array([d, null, e1, e2])
operator = np.ones(len(df), dtype=int) # dtype=int to use this as indexes
e1, e2, d1, d2 = (df.enabler1.values, df.enabler2.values, 
                  df.disabler1.values, df.disabler2.values)
operator[e1 & ~d1 & ~e2] = 2
operator[e2 & ~d2 & ~e1] = 3
operator[d1 | d2] = 0

rows = np.zeros((len(df), 3))
rows[0] = np.array([0, 0, 1])
for n, i in enumerate(operator[1:]):
    np.matmul(rows[n], operators[i], out=rows[n + 1])
df['result'] = np.sign(rows[:, 0] - rows[:, 1])

This works at least 10 times faster than recursive version on my system. Also, optimization with dropping no-effect rows could be combined with this method as well.
There is probably some form of vector representing and matrix operators for the variant with disabler2 = True & prev = 1 situations if it is possible.

thank you for the answer, especially for the update with the 2nd approach that is more in line with what I'm looking for, working mainly in a layer like NumPy. In fact, it has been a smart conclusion what you mention about the status transformations, because in the scenario for this question, there aren't situations where in the same row previous_result == 1 & disabler2 == True nor previous_result == -1 & disabler1 == True. Just included this consideration in the main post, and I will be testing the code with dataframes of different lengths to compare its running speed.

@codev happy to hear this, it was pleasure for me to think about this puzzle too) If there are some other impossible combinations, please mention them, it could simplify task dramatically

Also, if you are interested in theory, what exactly are these vectors and matrixes, you could check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix#Affine_transformations

I had forgotten to ask you if you have thought in a possible solution that doesn't content an explicit Python loop. I think it is possible to do that in some way working only with NumPy and finally just representing the arrays in Pandas columns. I've been trying with different things but haven't found a solution for the moment. Btw, certainly, your updated second code works significantly faster than the first one, and it is notably improvement. Finally, yes, it is very interesting to learn about vector operations, also for the speed benefit they provide.

You can mask loop by using itertools.accumulate (https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) but it didn't give me any speed bonuses and unfortunately numpy native accumulate (https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.accumulate.html) doesn't work with matmul function.

Also, I want to pay attention to the fact that your own second version of function work much faster than first (maybe first is so slow because of that global variables calls?). On my desktop your first function run ~2100 microseconds, your second function - ~90 ms and my function ~70 ms - the difference between your second and my version is pretty subtle compared to the gargantuan gap between your first and second versions.

About my own 2nd version, it was around a starting point, later also tried with a for loop using zip() to process lists in parallel, and after that point I've been trying to find ways where Python be used just to call a process that can handle the heavy work in a lower layer maybe in something like C/C++ (even not being something super optimized) and ideally using vectorization if possible. The 1st code version in the question is also as reference to hopefully provide ideas for other users here about improved solutions. And yes, I also thought that global variables could be slowing it down

I have tried with multiple ways but don't remember to try with itertools.accumulate, but I do remember to try to see if some kind of accumulate calculation in NumPy would work, but unfortunately, I couldn't find a way that obtain the required result. Maybe there could be some other mathematical library that can handle in a very efficient way this kind of situation about to update a status based on a previous status.
